# Stall Internet Activity When App is Terminated

Tags: c#, .net, networking, proxy, fiddler

I'm messing around with the FiddlerCore and .NET and making an Internet Filter application. I'd like to "stall" or prevent Internet Activity if the app isn't running, similar to how [Covenant Eyes](http://www.covenanteyes.com/) behaves when it is terminated or logged out.

I'd like to implement a similar behavior. I tried just not closing the FiddlerCore at all, which *works* but the proxy can easily be removed by anyone who knows what they're doing.
Doing this:

```
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877,fcsf);
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += new SessionStateHandler(FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

and never calling `Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();` works, as mentioned (HTTP[s] connections fail), but connectivity is easily restored by removing that proxy. 
I tried setting FiddlerCore to not be the system proxy (using: `FiddlerCoreStartupFlags fcsf = FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default;
            fcsf = (fcsf & ~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy);` ) but it still seemed to setup a proxy.

Basically, I'd like to hang connectivity when the app stops running, and restore it when it loads back up. Any ideas? Lemme know if i need to provide any more information. Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you'd have to go with writing a network driver. Can't see how else could you do such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this.  Fiddler is just a proxy, and Windows allows users to change their proxy settings.

Comment: Technically, you could use Group Policy to prevent the user from changing their proxy settings.